# Oracle DB read queries performance boost

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, rdbms

I am using Oracle database and there are cases where we are querying all the rows (selecting few but not all column names) from the table (in some cases, view created on table(s)). I want to increase the performance of my select query. I am using a primary key in the tables.

For example there is a table: Table (id, a, b, c, d, e, f) has 100k rows. I am querying it as follows:

```
SELECT c, d, f FROM Table;
```

I have tried using MATERIALIZED VIEWS, but practically, found almost no performance boost.

I thought about using PARTITIONS, but then I thought that I am scanning all the rows (but not all the columns), so would partitioning help in this case?

Comment: Maybe you should consider table compression: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables002.htm#CJAGFBFG

Comment: If you're only selecting a large number of rows then the bottleneck is almost certainly the network between the database and the application reading from it.  But why would you frequently select all the rows from a table?  Why would a user or an application frequently want to view 100,000 rows?

Comment: Displaying 100k rows is a performance test for your SQL client, not for the database. Why do you think a MVIEW would make retrieving **all** rows faster? You would still retrieve 100k rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

If you are selecting all rows, you are selecting a lot of data.  Removing a small number of columns probably will have little impact on performance -- unless the columns you are leaving out are really wide.  After all, the database engine still needs to read *all* the data pages, and return almost all the data.

If you do have wide columns, then you might be able to reduce the time by using a materialized view (with the associated overhead), or storing the commonly used columns in the one table and the rest in another table (vertical partitioning).

Finally, 100,000 records is a lot of records to return to an application.  I wouldn't be surprised if you could do more work in the database and reduce the amount of data being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your columns type/data, 100,000 records is not too much to retrieve. It is too much if you are retrieving large types, like `BLOB` and `CLOB`. Well, it all relies on the config of the machine running your Oracle server, but I'm assuming it has a reasonable config.

I executed a query just like you in an Oracle table with 386,843 rows... it returned three `NUMBER` columns for each row in 8.25 seconds... considering the amount of data, it's not that slow...

The `EXPLAIN PLAN` says it did an index `FAST FULL SCAN`, but as all data is been retrieved, a `FULL TABLE SCAN` should not represent a performance problem also.

I think you should check two points:

1. How much clients will execute this functionally at the same time? Lets say, 500 simultaneous access... it's a big load to your database/network, even with some data cache...
2. Isn't the network delaying your job? You may find a problem here...

Can't you just load data "on demand"? Retrieve 5,000 rows each time. It's a better way to handle your use case. This way, a table/index partitioning might  be of great help.